# Typescript addEventListener set event type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do this

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e: MouseEvent) => { ...
```

However, Typescript cannot know the exact event type based on event name.

`'click'` => `MouseEvent`

and thinks the type of `e` is of type `Event`. As is in definition

```
declare type EventListenerOrEventListenerObject = EventListener | EventListenerObject;
    
interface EventListener {
    (evt: Event): void;
}
    
interface EventListenerObject {
    handleEvent(evt: Event): void;
}
```

It obviously complains

> TS2345: Argument of type '(e: MouseEvent) => void' is
> not assignable to parameter of type
> 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.   Type '(e: MouseEvent) => void'
> is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
> Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 25 more.

How can I tell Typescript the `e` is of type `MouseEvent`? Or if I asked more generally: how to type `addEventListener` properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In version 3.3.3333 they defined this way in the lib.dom.ts.

```
    addEventListener<K extends keyof DocumentEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Document, ev: DocumentEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
```

Where *DocumentEventMap* is an interface that extends  *GlobalEventHandlersEventMap* where the click event is declared.

```
interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
    ...
    "click": MouseEvent;
    ...
}
```

As in the first signature, *type*  paramater type is a key **K** of *DocumentEventMap* and *ev* parameter type is mapped to *DocumentEventMap*[**K**], the compiler can infer the correct type for the e in the callback function.

Comment: Looks cool but it seems they added it only on `document` https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b145eaf160e6b2729aaacb89856bc2346f85ac4c/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4571 However, seems like the top answer as it's simply not implemented yet on `Element`. Thanks!